# Опля, hoppla — этимология

Tags: этимология

Русское междометие "опля" от немецкого "hoppla"?

Answer (score 1):

[опля́](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-Efremova-term-61632.htm) (в словаре Ефремовой)
**1.** *предикатив*
Возглас при прыжке, скачке или при физическом усилии как действие; оп (1*).
**2.** *межд. разг.*
Употр. как призыв к прыжку, скачку, физическому усилию; оп (2*).

В немецком языке нет слова hoppla, разве что похожее «hoppelpoppel (нем.) - n -s,
= террит. разг. 1. жареный картофель с ветчиной, залитый яйцами
2. яичный пунш», но это совсем другое.
«Hops (нем.)- муж. -es, -e разг. прыжок, скачок einen Hops machen - (под)прыгнуть mit einem Hops über den Zaun springen* (s) - одним махом перемахнуть через забор» [Немецкий словарь]
Опля от хоп-ля ! где «хоп» от hops – прыжок (нем.) > hippo – лошадь (греч.) > kobbila – кобыла (слав.)(редукция k/h, b/p, пропуск l)
Гауптман – hauptmann – военный чин в нем. армии (нем.) > kobilnj muinij – кобыльный мужний (слав.)
Производные от «хоп» – гиппопотам (букв. водная лошадь-греч.) hippopotam > kobilnaj potochnaj – кобыльная поточная (слав.);  ипподром (греч.) > hippodrome > kobilni-dorojnij – кобыльный дорожный (слав.)
«Ля» от ля-ля, тру-ля-ля, о-ля-ля, Олей-олей ! срав. ура ! (русск.)(редукция r/l)
Интересно, что hops связано с happy – счастливый (англ.), срав. Happy New Year ! – Счастливого нового года ! (англ.) через hlop – хлоп ! (слав.) хлопок ладонями – выражение радости, а также с кобылой, поскольку в английском есть значение happy – езда на кобылке ребёнка (англ.), иначе, выражение радости.
Все преобразования слов через мой метод поиска славянских корней в иностранных словах http://www.tezan.ru/metod.htm

Comment: Пожалуйста, улучшите форматирование Вашего ответа, чтобы сделать его более читаемым.

Comment: В немецком языке [есть слово hoppla](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/hoppla).

Comment: Ух ты! Давненько Вас не было. Рада вашему возвращению.